# How to remove a word or two at the end of string in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, gsub, stringr

I have a dataframe with a row called "Country". When the country of origin is the United States, the entries are listed as "Louisiana - USA", for example. I am trying to get rid of the "- USA" at the end, so that it will only say which state it came from.

So, I have something like this currently (though mine is thousands of entries):

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:4, Country = c("Louisiana - USA", "Canada","France", "Maine - USA"))
```

What I tried was the following:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    df$USA[i] <- ifelse(grepl(" USA| États-Unis", df$Country[i]), 1, 0) 
}

index_USA <- which(df$USA == 1)

for (int in index_USA) {
    gsub(" - USA", "", df$Country[int])
}
```

However, this code is not working. 
I also tried using the stringr package instead of gsub. So, I replaced the last for loop with:

```
for (int in index_USA) {
    str_replace_all(df$Country[int], " - USA", "")
}
```

But this did not work either. I feel like I'm making an obvious mistake, but I cannot figure it out (perhaps I need to use regex?)

Comment: `df$Country <- gsub(" - USA","",df$Country)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove `" USA"` and `" États-Unis"` at the end of the string. So, you need

```
df$Country <- sub("\\s+(?:USA|États-Unis)$", "", df$Country)
```

**Details**

- `\\s+` - 1 or more whitespace chars
- `(?:` - start of a (non-capturing) grouping construct, matching either of the two alternatives:

  - `USA`  - `USA` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `États-Unis` - `États-Unis` substring
- `)` - end of the grouping
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these codes:

```
df$Country <- sub(" - USA","",df$Country)
df
#Or if you want to you use package stringr
df$Country <- str_replace_all(df$Country," - USA","")
df
```